# NotMapped not working with Observable properties

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have a class that I use to map to a SQL database I have certain columns I use in my view model that I do not wish to store, however the `NotMapped` data annotation seems to be ignored.

For connecting my SQL Database I am using SQLKata.

A resulting save of an object with these fields produces an error that states that the `notmapped` columns do not exist

```
    [ObservableProperty, Ignore, NotMapped]
    private long time;

    [Key, Ignore, ObservableProperty]
    private int id;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string family;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string model;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string status;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool isLocked;

    [ObservableProperty, Ignore, NotMapped]
    private string timeTracker;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int count;
```

Comment: My apologies meant to just put C# must have tabbed over the wrong one. Fixed

Comment: This is not MAUI related. I'm assuming the `[ObservableProperty]` attribute comes from the MVVM Toolkit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

I have found a suitable workaround for this although it is less than optimal. I currently have a View Model that mimics the fields in my DataBase Model however it adds fields that I wish to use in the View but not store. This results in me needing to convert between the objects when doing CRUD operations.